# IntegrityError while I am programmatically committing user to database - Django

Tags: python, django

In Django I am trying to create a log-in view that would accept a default username and default password.  This would allow the log-in view to just accept the username 'test' and password 'test', this would allow the user to be authenticated without registration.  The problem I am running into is utilizing `create_user()`.  I have tried to create the variable `default_user = User.objects.create_user(username = 'test', password = 'test')`

This just gives me an IntegrityError.  I have tried to create code to handle the IntegrityError in a try/except block but continue to bump my head against the wall.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import LoginForm


default_user = User.objects.create_user(username = 'test', password = 'test')

def index(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate(request,
                                username = cd['username'],
                                password = cd['password'])
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponse('Authenticated '\
                                        'successfully')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('disabled account')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid Login')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'server/index.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Would be helpful to see the full error trace. Does the user `test` already exist? the username as to be unique

Comment: Could you post the full traceback, and the your `models.py` and `forms.py`?

Comment: I believe I was able to get the code to work by creating the variable ```default_user = User.objects.create_user(password = 'test', user = 'test')``` outside of the function.